# Using environment variables for mysql database password and host throws errors

Tags: python, mysql, django, environment-variables

I'm trying to set up a mysql database and secure sensitive information in an .env file. I was able to successfully store the database `NAME`, but using environment variables for the `PASSWORD` and `HOST` throws two different errors:

Error for `PASSWORD`:

```
Exception Type: OperationalError at /
Exception Value: (1045, "Access denied for user 'studio413'@'10.0.0.32' (using password: NO)")
```

Error for `HOST`:

```
AttributeError at /
'NoneType' object has no attribute 'startswith'
```

Putting the actual `PASSWORD` and `HOST` directly into the `settings.py` works perfectly, and I believe I've properly set up the environment variables, as the database `NAME` works fine.

Typing `echo $DATABASE_PASSWORD` and `echo $DATABASE_HOST` into my console yields the correct information from my .env file.

I'm using PythonAnywhere and followed the instructions for setting up environment variables here: https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/environment-variables-for-web-apps/

If it helps, here is my `settings.py` file:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'studio413$default',
        'USER': os.getenv("DATABASE_USER"),
        'PASSWORD': os.getenv("DATABASE_PASSWORD"),
        'HOST': os.getenv("DATABASE_HOST"),
    }
}
```

If anyone could help me solve this, I would greatly appreciate it!

Note: I tried providing the full traceback for each error, but stackoverflow would not let me post them (it thought I was posting spam).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured out the issue.

For anyone running into this problem on PythonAnywhere, there are two different `wsgi.py` files. The first one is found in the same directory as `settings.py` (which was the one I was working with), while the other is under the "Web" tab and linked under the "Code:" section. The latter is the one that needed to be edited. Adding the following to that `wsgi.py` file (above the `application = get_wsgi_application()` line) got all my environment variables working properly:

```
from dotenv import load_dotenv

project_folder = os.path.expanduser('~/<insert-your-project-directory-here>')
load_dotenv(os.path.join(project_folder, '.env'))
```

Comment: Can you expand more your answer, please ? What is the file wsgi.py and where do you find it ?

Comment: @Kiwi The `wsgi.py` file contains the specifications for how your application communicates with a web server (and vice versa). This [blog post](https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/what-is-wsgi-web-server-gateway-interface-ed2d290449e) explains what WSGI is.

I explained where to find the `wsgi.py` file above, but to be more specific: you can find your local `wsgi.py` under the same folder as your `settings.py` (assuming you're using the default Django file structure). If you’re deploying your application to PythonAnywhere, then you can find their `wsgi.py` by following my steps above